# Drupal Domain Redirection

Tags: ssl, drupal, lamp, mediatemple

We have two domains: www.example.com and www.example.org. Both point to the same site. But, we'd like everything to point to .org. We are running Drupal on a LAMP server hosted by Media Temple.

We have now started to have problems because our .com SSL cert expired, so anybody who goes to the .com site routinely gets scary messages in Chrome, etc.

How can we make it so that if somebody goes to https://www.example.com in google, they get nicely directed to http://www.example.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this multiple ways.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / https://www.exmaple.org
```

**In a PHP file**

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: https://www.example.org");
header("Connection: close");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this module :

https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_301_redirect

This is the domain that all other domains that point to this site will be 301 redirected to. This value should also include the scheme (http or https)

I Hope help you!